# probability of an event happening over a year

Tags: probability

If I am calculating the probability of something happening over a year and there is say a 10 percent chance per month it will happen I know that if it happened say in August, September and October I would do, .10*.10*.10 which is 1/1000,
but how would I calculate the probability of it happening once from June to August?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options: either it happened in June (and didn't happen in July and August), in July alone or in August alone.
The probability that it happened in one of the months, say June, and not happened in the others, is, similar to what you said: $0.10 \cdot 0.90 \cdot 0.90$ (there is a $90$% chance it won't happen). Therefore the solution is $3 \cdot 0.10 \cdot 0.90 \cdot 0.90$.

Comment: I knew the 90 percent chance came in somewhere but could not get my head around it, thanks very much. So if I wanted to calculate the probability of it happening in two of the three months would it be 3*.10*.10*.90

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, but note that the factor of $3$ in your expression comes from there being ${3 \choose 2} = 3$ distinct pairs of months, which just so happens to be the same amount as before, ${3 \choose 1} = 3$. If we were dealing with $4$ months instead, the corresponding factor in the expression for the probability of it happening in two of the four months would be ${4 \choose 2} = 6 \neq 4 = {4 \choose 1}$.

Comment: @Sam I am calculating the result as 0.027, is this correct or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, that seems to be correct. The probability that something happens in two specific months is $0.009$ and there are three different pairs of months. But then again, I too could be missing something obvious ...!

Comment: @Sam well more chance of me missing than you I fear :) One last question,  if the question were rephrased to probability of it happening two or more times in say September, October and November and looking at it over a twelve month period does the outcome of what happens in previous months have any effect on the current months  or is each event  independent from the next like a coin toss.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Both ronash and I assumed that the events are independent. It wouldn't make sense for the events to depend on each other unless this dependence is explained in the question. If the question were rephrased to the probability of it happening two *or more* times, you could consider the two cases that it happens in exactly two of the months and in exactly three (all) of the months. Seeing as these two are mutually exclusive, you can add the resulting probabilities.

Comment: That has been a huge help, I fear I will be back!, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probabilities are actually easy to calculate with, as long as the individual events are *independent* of each other:

If you are looking for an **and** (i.e. A and B happens), you multiply the probabilities. If the probability for A is 50% and for B 10%, the probability that both A and B happen is 0.5*0.1 = 0.05 = 5%.

If you are looking for an **or** (i.e. either A or B or both happen), you sum the **inverse** of the probability and substract it from 1. With the above A and B, the probability that either (or both) happen is 1 - (1-0.5) * (1-0.1) = 1 - 0.5 * 0.9 = 1 - 0.45 = 0.55 or 55%

This follows from fundamental logic and De Morgan's Law:

- A + !A = 1
- !(A or B) = !A and !B

Comment: I realize that you posted this Answer some time ago, but then it was also written years after the original Question to which it responds.  Probabilities are not as "actually easy to calculate" as you describe.  While you wrote that to get "A and B" you "sum the probabilities, this is never true unless both are zero probability events.  You then proceed to illustrate by multiplying rather than adding the probabilities of A and B, but even that would be correct only if these were *independent* events.    I'm not in a hurry to downvote if you are motivated to edit or delete the post.

Comment: Language. Of course multiply. I'll edit the answer.